# findbugs linking report to source code

Tags: java, maven, static-analysis, findbugs, spotbugs

How to link source code files in Findbugs report generated using maven?

The requirement is to navigate from the Findbugs HTML report to source code file cross references generated using jxr plugin or to the actual source code files.

maven command used: `mvn compile jxr:jxr findbugs:findbugs xml:transform`

The linking doesn't work with the following maven configuration. In the HTML report I could not find any links to navigate to the source file. However, the same do work in Jenkins build (some plugins takes care i guess).

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>                
            <configuration>
                <effort>max</effort>
                <maxHeap>1024</maxHeap>
                <threshold>Low</threshold> <!-- Reports all bugs (other values are medium and max) -->
                <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
                <failOnError>false</failOnError>
                <!-- findbugs output directory -->
                <outputDirectory>${env.WORKSPACE}/static_analysis/findbugs</outputDirectory>
                <xmlOutputDirectory>${env.WORKSPACE}/static_analysis/findbugs</xmlOutputDirectory>
                <findbugsXmlOutputDirectory>${env.WORKSPACE}/static_analysis/findbugs</findbugsXmlOutputDirectory>
                <xrefLocation>${env.WORKSPACE}/static_analysis/xref</xrefLocation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2-beta-1</version>
            <configuration>
                <transformationSets>
                    <transformationSet>
                        <!-- Configures the source directory of XML files. -->
                        <dir>${env.WORKSPACE}/static_analysis/findbugs</dir>
                        <!-- Configures the directory in which the FindBugs report is written.-->
                        <outputDir>${env.WORKSPACE}/static_analysis</outputDir>
                        <stylesheet>fancy-hist.xsl</stylesheet>
                        <fileMappers>
                            <!-- Configures the file extension of the output files. -->
                            <fileMapper implementation="org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.filemappers.FileExtensionMapper">
                                <targetExtension>.html</targetExtension>
                            </fileMapper>
                        </fileMappers>
                    </transformationSet>
                </transformationSets>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>findbugs</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", that doesn't provide us much to work with. Please edit your question so we can help.

Comment: First: test with the latest version of the plugin which is SpotBugs Maven Plugin.